# Bing maps rest service get full addresses from postcode

Tags: rest, bing-maps, postal-code

I was wondering if there was functionality in the Bing maps API that allows you specify a postcode and it returns all possible addresses within that postcode area?

For example, on some sites when entering your address, you have the option to specify just your postcode and click a button to find the address. This will typically produce a dropdown list of all possible addresses found at that postcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no functionality to do that in Bing Maps. The closest thing you would be able to do is geocode a postal code and then reverse geocode a bunch of points in the surrounding area until you stop getting addresses with the same postal code. This would be very slow and would generate a lot of transactions against your Bing Maps account. You can find a code sample of how to reverse geocode over an area here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/reverse-geocoding-over-a-search-area/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Like you say, the solution isn't ideal and would be quite costly in the long run.